# Couldn't build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max

Tags: flutter, arm64

i am trying to run my code on iOS simulator, but it keeps giving me this error. I have tried a lot of things, but it doesn't help. i don't know is it problem with cocoapods cauz i had error with it, but know it's fixed but i have new error

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[11011]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x20457bad8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x113f6c2b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[11011]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x20457bb28) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x113f6c308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/justhateulol/FlutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/jitsi_meet-4.0.0/ios/Classes/JitsiViewController.swift:8:41: error: cannot find type 'PiPViewCoordinator' in scope
        fileprivate var pipViewCoordinator: PiPViewCoordinator?
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/justhateulol/FlutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/jitsi_meet-4.0.0/ios/Classes/JitsiViewController.swift:87:30: error: cannot find 'PiPViewCoordinator' in scope
            pipViewCoordinator = PiPViewCoordinator(withView: jitsiMeetView)
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/justhateulol/FlutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/jitsi_meet-4.0.0/ios/Classes/JitsiViewController.swift:102:30: error: 'nil' requires a contextual type
            pipViewCoordinator = nil
                                 ^
    /Users/justhateulol/FlutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/jitsi_meet-4.0.0/ios/Classes/JitsiViewController.swift:8:41: error: cannot find type 'PiPViewCoordinator' in scope
        fileprivate var pipViewCoordinator: PiPViewCoordinator?
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Edited and added my Podfile. Also i though that problem could be in iOS version, but it didn't work

```
platform :ios, '11.0'


ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
       config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
     end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this since cloning an old project, and upgrading Flutter to 2.5.1. I managed to get my project working again with this:

Open your `Podfile`

Uncomment your platform minimum at the top (some firebase plugins require 10.0 now)

`platform :ios, '10.0'`

Set the code at the bottom like this:

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

*Optionally try to update the plugins*

Run `flutter pub outdated` and then and try to update as much as you can (it may require some code migration) with `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`

Update the pods now that you just migrated to latest versions for your plugins.
First delete `Podfile.lock` file then `cd ios` then run `pod repo update`

`cd..` to return to the main project folder

Finally, run  `flutter clean` then open XCode and `clean build folder`, and now try for a `flutter run`. Hope that helped, spent hours on this.

Comment: i tried everything u told and now it gives me another error. "Error running pod install"

Comment: Hmm post your podfile

Comment: edited already, u can check

Comment: Is there a linebreak at `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` in your podfile or is that just the formatting on SO?

Comment: it's just formatting